# How to greet someone when you meet them at night

Tags: single-word-requests, greetings

Is there any formal salutation to greet someone when you meet them at night? A prefix such as 'Good' with morning, afternoon and evening works well but implies altogether a diferent meaning when used with night. To be specific, what can be prefixed with night here or any better way of 'greeting' will also work.
P. S:-Informal greetings like hello and hi won't work here.

Answer (score 1):

"Good Evening" or any other way of formally greeting someone. It's pretty tricky not to use "Good Night" considering the connotations of the word, so I would avoid it if you aren't comfortable pulling that out at any given moment.